# Error with stockfish library when building a unity project for WebGl

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, build, webgl

I have a chess game where I integrated stockfish and saved it in "Assets/Plugins/stockfish_15_win_x64_popcnt".

[folder content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DbFPt.png)

The game is working in the unity playmode, but when I try to build it for WebGL i get errors in the files from stockfish.

[errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Fg7N.png),

[error detail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mig8O.png).

I found something about the error "no template named 'optional' in namespace 'std'" from "bool save_eval(const std::optionalstd::string& filename);" here https://github.com/pistacheio/pistache/issues/905 but I don't know how to solve it using unity and rider as IDE and especially that the game works in playmode.

I tried building for Windows instead of WebGl and for windows the build works but I dont have the plugin there. But after I copied it from the project and added it in the Plugins folder in the build it worked and i could play the game with the bot.

The issue is that I want to make a WebGl build and its not working.
I think I'm missing something but don't know what.

Hopefully I have explained the problem well.

Does anyone have an idea on how can I solve it?

Thanks!

Comment: Who said it was compatible with webgl? If it’s calling the exe in there it won’t be

Comment: Ok, then how can I solve it? How can I use stockfish for WebGL?

Comment: Ask them? It looks to be commandline based which wont work easily as it stands